# Basic identities of logical expressions and deriving logical expressions from truth table?

Tags: boolean, logic, expression, truthtable

I was wondering what a basic identity of a logical expression is and how to get it. I looked on google but couldn't find anything about it.

Say, for example I have a logical expression ~(~(P ^ ~(P ^ Q)) ^ ~(Q ^ ~(P ^ Q)))
Below is the result I got from a truth table and I don't know what to do with it to get a basic identity.

```
0
1
1
0
```

As well, as that I have a truth table and I have no idea how to derive a logical expression from it.

```
P Q R F 

0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1    
1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have the truth table, creating a DNF formula is trivial.  Take a look at where the assignment is true.  Then you end you end up with (exclamation mark means *negation*)

```
(P & !Q & R) OR (P & Q & !R) OR (P & Q & R).
```